# Error with Form Key Validation on logout

Tags: magento-1.9, form-key

I just enabled form key validation and there's an error showing up on logout:

My Magento version is 1.9.2.2 with last patch 9767 applied

```
Invalid method Mage_Core_Model_Session::renewFormKey(Array
(
)
)

Trace:
#0 /var/www/magento07/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php(311): Varien_Object->__call('renewFormKey', Array)
#1 /var/www/magento07/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php(311): Mage_Core_Model_Session->renewFormKey()
#2 /var/www/magento07/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php(255): Mage_Customer_Model_Session->_logout()
#3 /var/www/magento07/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php(236): Mage_Customer_Model_Session->logout()
#4 /var/www/magento07/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Customer_AccountController->logoutAction()
#5 /var/www/magento07/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('logout')
#6 /var/www/magento07/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#7 /var/www/magento07/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#8 /var/www/magento07/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#9 /var/www/magento07/index.php(86): Mage::run('', 'store')
#10 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the the below files are updated properly. This issue might be for 9767 patch.

```
app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/etc/system.xml 
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/formkey.phtml
```

Hope it will helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session.php`

This soluction may be solve your issue

[Magento 1.9.2.1 SUPEE-7405 admin not working](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98452/magento-1-9-2-1-supee-7405-admin-not-working?answertab=active#tab-top)